# Can update object from react app to .NET API post request method

Tags: c#, reactjs, axios, http-post

I built an API in .net and react app. In the react app I have a list
and I want to update one object on the list, this is the code:

```cs
const handleCheck =async(id)=>{

    const listItem = items.map((item)=>item.id===id?{...item,ischecked:!item.ischecked}:item); //go over all the list and update when 
    //the checkbox is check
 
    const myItem = listItem.filter((item) => item.id === id);
    console.log("the new item is:");
    console.log(myItem);
    setAndSave(listItem);
    

    const updateOption={ 
      
      method:'POST', // update checkbox
    //  method: 'PUT',
    headers:{
      'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
 
    body:JSON.stringify({ischecked:myItem[0].ischecked})

    };
    const result = await apiRequest(API_UPDATE,updateOption);
    if(result) setFetchError(result)
};
```

and the apiRequest.js is:

```
const apiRequest =async (url='',optionsObj =null,erreMsg=null)=>{
    
    try{
        const response = await fetch(url, optionsObj);
        console.log(response);
    if(!response.ok) throw Error('please reload the app');
    }catch(err){
        erreMsg = err.message;
        console.log(erreMsg);
    }finally{
    return erreMsg;
    }
}
export default apiRequest;
```